# scss - starting a partially named class

Tags: css, sass

I was wondering if it was possible to have a partially completed class name, which then I could fill in some how e.g.

```
.theme-color-* {
  happy {
    color: yellow
  }
  angry {
    color: red
  }
  sad {
    color: blue
  }
}
```

of course, this represents `.theme-color-happy, .theme-color-angry, .theme-color-sad`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, but you have to use [&](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#article-header-id-12):

```
.theme-color- {
  &happy {
    color: yellow
  }
  &angry {
    color: red
  }
  &sad {
    color: blue
  }
}
```